# HTML app Landscape Orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xcode, cordova

I have searched for hours for the answer to my question and have found nothing that seems to work. So please accept my apologies if this question has already been answered...

I am very new to app development and have been suggested to go down the route of html, css, jquery using XCODE and PhoneGap to build and compile.
After a lot of faffing, I've managed to build a html page and test it through XCODE.

My issue is I can not force the orientation to landscape.

I found answers to set the orientation in the .plist file which I have done. This changes the orientation of toolbars and viewing window, but the content (HTML) stays in portrait mode.

I found an example post where someone created a test app in landscape mode only, great I thought, but unfortunately this was in objective C.

For example this is in a file called ViewA.m

```
    // ViewA.m

#import "ViewA.h"

@implementation ViewA

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }

-(void)viewDidLoad
    {
//  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 768.0);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }

@end
```

Do these separate files work for HTML as well as Objective C?
Is there a jquery/javascript solution for html apps?

I appreciate this is a bit of a "bitty" question and there could be multiple answers. I would appreciate any help or direction someone could offer.

If this has been solved already, as I say sorry for a repeat question, but there are so many of similar questions, it's very hard to get through them all!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed a few people have looked. I've managed to find the answer to my question and wanted to post it, just incase anyone else is having a similar issue.

To get the content of an app written in HTML to appear in landscape mode you need to go (in xcode)
Folder (app name) -> Classes -> MainViewController.m

You will see:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Change this to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

And that should work :-)